# Login to Heroku on remote server without a browser

Tags: heroku

Is there a way to login into Heroku to see the logs on a remote server which has no browser installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Heroku CLI

```
$ heroku login -i
$ heroku logs
```

Comment: Try heroku login -i

Comment: Works! thanks. Strange why Heroku says on their help page that there is no alternative .. https://help.heroku.com/5I11S48T/i-need-to-log-in-to-the-cli-without-a-browser